# How to add JPEG comments to an existing JPEG image file

Tags: c++, c, libjpeg

Is there a way to add JPEG comments ("COM" markers) to an existing JPEG image file using libjpeg?

It is certainly possible to do so by first decompressing an existing image to an in-memory buffer and then compressing the raw image again with jpeg_write_marker( ... JPEG_COM ... ) to add comments, and saving to disk. Unless there is a need to decompress first, doing this seems to be an overkill.

Comment: Why close? Seems like a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a tool called [`wrjpgcom`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wrjpgcom), it's part of `libjpeg`. I think it does what you want. Perhaps you could look through its [source](http://libjpeg.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libjpeg/libjpeg/wrjpgcom.c?view=markup) to find out how it's done.

Comment: Thanks. wrjpgcom, unfortunately, does exactly what we're trying to avoid, namely make a copy of the original image ("... generates a new JPEG/JFIF file..."). This is what I meant by "an overkill" above... Ideally we would like to have an "in-place" modification of an existing image to set the JPEG comment.

Comment: @alexg, it doesn't seem to recompress the jpeg, it just rewrites the chunks to strip the old comments and replace them with the new ones. It looks like a normal way of doing it. Should be fast enough and no quality loss.

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't recompress, just makes a copy. Considering that the markers are not of fixed length in the file, there is no way to perform an in-place modification. Thanks a lot for your solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jpeg_write_marker()` during the writing of the output file to write the comment after setting it up.  Then, use `jpeg_read_coefficients()` and `jpeg_write_coefficients()` (in place of the ordinary `jpeg_read_scanlines()` and `jpeg_write_scanlines()`) to read and write the raw, compressed data without actually decompressing and recompressing it.

See the section "Really raw data: DCT coefficients" in the [libjpeg documentation](https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg/blob/master/libjpeg.txt#L2674).  Be sure to read all the caveats mentioned there.

Comment: We can't use this technique because the JPEG images are "given" to us by another component...

Comment: the link to the documentation is broken; I guess this is the same documentation? http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-87/tcl_ext/tkimg/tkimg/libjpeg/libjpeg.doc

Comment: @ChrisMaes: Thanks, yes, that's the same; I updated the link to a more recent version that's less likely to break in the future (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Someone may use JPEG Comment Editor created by Mwisoft. It automate adding / editing JPEG  comments using Windows,  instead of right-click JPEG file and click properties to manually add comments.